# Putting a variable in a select statement(mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to use a variable in a select statement in MySQL. Below is the code.

```
<?php 
        extract($_REQUEST);
        require_once("config.php");
        $q=mysql_query("select * from ads where location='$loc';");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
            ?>
            <table border="0" cellSpacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="images/classifieds/<?php echo $row['id'];?>.jpg" height="80" width="80">
                </td>
                <td >
                <span style="font-family:cambria;"><?php echo $row["content"];?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <?php
```

Here `$loc` is the location which am getting from another page. Depending on the value of this `$loc`, i have to get information from the database. It didn't work when i used this select statement.Please let me know your ideas.

Comment: `location = " . $loc . ";"`

Comment: simply `echo $loc;` and check what you are getting in this variable

Comment: Can you plesae echo the query and report back here with the result and the exact error text  getting?

Comment: yes echo $loc is working.

Comment: As said @Mureinik echo the query and run it with the MYSQL, and check for what it returns

Comment: when i echo the query "$q=mysql_query("select * from ads where location='$loc';");" it is displaying "Resource id #7".

Comment: I meant you should echo the SQL string itself: `$sql = "select * from ads where location='$loc';"; echo $str;`.

Comment: what was the result you got? a mysql error?

Comment: "select * from ads where `location` = '".$loc."' ";  try this.

Comment: I'm really sorry guys. The select statement was correct. I made a mistake while displaying the results. its working now.

Comment: $q=mysql_query("select * from ads where location='$loc';"); ??  Remove ';'  from inside brackets

Comment: at first, check whether do you get the value of $loc or not. I saw you user $_REQUEST method, so how you have got the $loc value? Please check do the get the $loc value correctly.

Comment: While you're working on that, you may want to read about SQL injections. The code you're trying to write (putting the value of a request parameter directly into an SQL query) is a classic SQL injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$q=mysql_query("select * from `ads` where `location`='$loc';");
```